# Android Studio MySql Login

Tags: android, mysql, authentication

I recently started using MySql to connect to my android app and I'm stuck at the login. I don't what's wrong but when I try to login, nothing happens.

Here's my PHP Code

```
<?php

$user_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username");
$user_pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password");


$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Hadassa1998", "vodadb");


$query = mysqli_query ($conn, "select * from vodainfos where username = 
'".$user_name."' and password = '".$user_pass."'");



if($rez= mysqli_fetch_array($conn)){

    echo "Login Réussi";
}
else{
echo "Echec Login";
}
?>
```

And Over here is my Java Code

```
    usrnm= findViewById(R.id.user_login);
    pass= findViewById(R.id.motdepasse);
    button= findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            loginclass();
        }
    });
}
```

Here's where the login Happens. I don't know what I am doing wrong 
I think the issue is with the URL but I am not sure. It won't open the next activity and it won't throw the error message either

The IP is a dummy

```
public void loginclass() {

 StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
"http://192.168.73.147/login.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.contains ("1")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
Menu.class));
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(Connexion.this, "Username ou Mot de passe 
incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }

    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params= new HashMap<>();

            params.put("username",usrnm.getText().toString());
            params.put("password", pass.getText().toString());
            return  params;
        }
    };

    Volley.newRequestQueue(Connexion.this).add(stringRequest);

}
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Thank you for the tips but I still don't know what's wrong with my code. Would you help ?

Comment: Don't fix your code. Use a framework where this is already a solved problem and then you can move on to building features that make your app distinctive, not wasting time re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Alrigth ! would you direct me to one ?

Comment: There's a lot of examples on how you can use frameworks like Laravel to build a [REST API](https://blog.pusher.com/build-rest-api-laravel-api-resources/). This makes building out mobile applications, which often depend on such things, pretty straightforward. As a bonus you can enable things like Facebook/Google/Twitter login without having to write a small mountain of code.